# Creating Custom Query

Tags: wp-query, array, meta-query

I've hit some sort of stumbling bock here, and I can't find my way over it.

I'm trying to craft a custom WP query that searches for posts by country of origin, selecting multiple countries at once.

I have a table that maps countries to regions, so the initial query will search for the selected region, and return all of the countries in that region as an array. For example, if you select Africa, it will return an array of countries within Africa.

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['region'])){
     $region = $_REQUEST['region'];

    $regionresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery_regions WHERE region='$region'") or die(mysql_error());
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($regionresult);

    if (!$regionresult) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
        die($message);
    }
} else {
     $region = NULL;
}
```

That part works.

Now, I want to use the returning array to search my WP posts for any that originated from any of the countries in the array. This is the part I can't get to work:

```
$country_search = array(mysql_fetch_array($regionresult));
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'Country',
            'value' => '$country_search',
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I get no results back. In fact, if include `echo "$args";`, what I get back is simply the word "Array." I also only want it to return results from a specific category.

I'm sure that I'm overlooking something simple. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following codes:

```
    $country_search_array = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($regionresult)){
        $country_search_array[] = $row['country']; // Your country field name
    }
    $country_search = "'".implode("',", $country_search_array)."'";

$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'Country',
                'value' => $country_search,
                'compare' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Well, that is certainly getting me down the road. There was a single quote missing from the implode statement, but this is what `$args` returns now: `Array
([posts_per_page] =&gt; -1 [meta_query] =&gt; Array ( [0] =&gt; Array ([key] =&gt; Country [value] =&gt; 'Algeria','Angola','Benin','Botswana','Burkina Faso','Burundi','Cape Verde','Central African Republic','Chad',... [compare] =&gt; IN )))`

Comment: It's still not returning any posts, though.

Comment: Here is where I am now: http://tylonius.com/gallery-test.html

Comment: Just remove this line:

$country_search = "'".implode("',", $country_search_array)."'";

Comment: That's what generates the search array. Without it, `value' => $country_search` becomes an undeclared value.

Comment: I have try in my local machine and its working. is still your query does not work? if not, please update query output in your test file gallery-test.html

Comment: Nope. Removing that line generates a server error.

Comment: This example work for me. I don't have any country database, so I create a country array.

[code]
$country_search = array('Algeria', 'Angola', 'Benin');
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'Country',
            'value' => $country_search,
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
$country_query = new WP_Query( $args );
[/code]

Please make check again your post type name (post or page) and country meta key name (country instead Country)

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but the dynamic array value is a large part of what makes it all work. Also, "Country" is the existing meta_key name. I agree that it should be "country," but more often than not, we have to work within the client's existing structure. We get the cookies we get, and they crumble the way that they do. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `'$country_search'` as a literal value, it should be

```
'value' => $country_search
```

without single quotes.

Also, I recommend replacing those old mysql query functions with [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I actually went back and forth on that trying to determine if that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there were two array objects:

```
$country_search = array(mysql_fetch_array($regionresult));
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'Country',
            'value' => '$country_search',
            'compare' => 'IN',
            'category' => 'Gallery'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

It should have been this:

```
$country_search = array(mysql_fetch_array($regionresult));
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
            'key' => 'Country',
            'value' => '$country_search',
            'compare' => 'IN',
            'category' => 'Gallery'
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```